# Execute queries until non-empty result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three queries, looking like these:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 'a'
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Column2 = 'b'
SELECT * FROM Table1 A, Table2 B WHERE A.Column1 <> B.Column1
```

Now all logic is implemented on the client side as following. Execute the first query, if HasRows, set a flag to 1 and return the rows. Otherwise execute the second query, if HasRows, set the flag to 2 and return the rows. Otherwise execute the third query, set the flag to 3 and return the rows.

How to do this with a single query? Flag stuff, I guess, should be solved adding Flag to the queries:

```
SELECT Flag = 1, * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 'a'
SELECT Flag = 2, * FROM Table2 WHERE Column2 = 'b'
SELECT Flag = 3, * FROM Table1 A, Table2 B WHERE A.Column1 <> B.Column1
```

But now what? How to check, if a query returns non-empty result?

Also, I'd like to cache the results, in other words, to avoid executing the same query twice - once for checking and the second time - for returning data.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a table variable to store the result and only return it at the end of the SQL block.  Checking `@@rowcount` would tell you if the previous `insert` added any rows; if it's zero, you can run further queries:

```
declare @result table (flag int, col1 int, col2 varchar(50))
insert @result select 1, col1, col2 from Table1 where Column1 = 'a'
if @@rowcount = 0 
    begin
    insert @result select 2, col1, col2 from Table2 where Column1 = 'b'
    end
if @@rowcount = 0 
    begin
    insert @result select 3, col1, col2 from Table1 A, Table2 B 
        where A.Column1 <> B.Column1
    end

select * from @result
```

This approach only works if each `select` has the same column definition.